# Potential on equatorial line of a dipole is zero,while electric field is present.How?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, dipole

E=-dv/dr.   But V=0 at equitorial line of a dipole and E  is not 0.Can anyone please help me how this is true?    Whenever function is 0,its derivative is always 0 i.e. if.  f(x)=0 then f'(x)=0 . Here f(x) is V which is 0,but f'(x) which is E is not 0. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You have a **misconception** with derivatives. If a function is zero at a point does it mean its derivative is also zero at that point?

Consider $f(x) = x$. Now the derivative $f'(x) = 1 =$ a constant. We have $f(0)=0$, but $f'(0)=1$ right?

Answer (score 0):

$E$ is NOT $-dV/dr$: this only holds for spherically symmetric fields, which the dipole is not.  The correct relation is
$$
\vec E=-\vec\nabla V =-
\left(\hat r\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}+\hat \theta\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial V}{\partial \theta}+\hat \phi\frac{1}{r\sin\theta}\frac{\partial V}{\partial\phi}\right)
$$
so there might be some $\hat \theta$ and $\hat \phi$ components in there which need not be $0$ even if $\partial V/\partial r=0$.